# perform single query count on model with array of ids?

Tags: mongoose

i have this code, a book can have many comments, i want to put their counts on an array

```
const bookCommentsLoader = new DataLoader(async bookIds => {
  const comments = await Comment.count({
    bookId: { $in: bookIds }
  })
  ...
})
```

the problem with graphql dataloader is that, when returned, the result and length of ids must match, so i want it to return this this:

```
model id-> ['1','3','12'] must return model counts like [5,7,1]
```

i dont want to use loop caust it will send multiple query, i want to use single query, help?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum

You would use an aggregate

```
var aggregatePipeline = [
    {$group: {_id: "$bookId", numOfComments: {$sum: 1}}
];


Comments.aggregate(aggregatePipeline, (error, results) => {
    // results comes out to be [{_id: bookId, numOfComments: Number}, ....]
    // From here, you can map the array to the format you wish
    var formattedArray = results.map(o => return(o.numOfComments))

    console.log(formattedArray);
});
```

UPDATED - to pass in specific IDs

```
function getCountOfSpecificBookIds(bookIds){
  var aggregatePipeline = [
    {$match: {bookId: {$in: bookIds}},
    {$group: {_id: "$bookId", numOfComments: {$sum: 1}}
  ];

  Comments.aggregate(aggregatePipeline, (error, results) => {
    // results comes out to be [{_id: bookId, numOfComments: Number}, ....]
    // From here, you can map the array to the format you wish
    var formattedArray = results.map(o => return(o.numOfComments))

    console.log(formattedArray);
  });
}
```

Comment: how do you pass specific ids?

Comment: This pipeline will group all your ids for you. If you want get specificIds, you can also include a $match in your pipeline.

var aggregatePipeline = [
    {$match: {bookId: {$in: bookIds}},
    {$group: {_id: "$bookId", numOfComments: {$sum: 1}}
];

That will count each bookId within that array of bookIds

Comment: Wrapped the code in a function to demonstrate how to get counts for specific IDs